# How to force Entity framework to use my comparator

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following problem.

I need to delete from database context item with related objects. (Object Building has property List)

I have list with old database object created just like this:

```
List<Building> oldContext = db.Buildings.Include(o => o.Rooms).ToList();
```

And then List of new objects from web servise

```
List<Building> newContext = CallService();
```

Then I set two variables - buildings I would like to delete from db:

```
BuildingToDelete1 = oldContext.FirstOrDefault(o => new BuildingComparer().Equals(o, newContext[0]))

BuildingToDelete2 = newContext[0]
```

But whet I do this:

```
db.Buildings.Attach(BuildingToDelete1);
db.Buildings.Remove(BuildingToDelete1);
db.SaveChanges();
```

It works great... Problem is when I try to do the same with variable BuildingToDelete2 - it throws exception however both variables have almost same content(for example ID is different)

My Ask is how to force Entity framework compare objecst with my BuildingComparer().

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all. EF can only work with constructs that can go into the database - i.e. transalted into LINQ. Your comparer can not.

Pull without them, then switch to LINQ to objects - by making the EF query AsEnumreable(). After that processing happens in your process, so the SQL translation requirements do not apply.